# How to change column value by matching row value in data frame?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, tuples

Say I do have the following table

| longitude | latitude | temperature | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | y | z | 1 |
| p | q | r | 2 |
| a | b | c | 1 |
| k | l | m | 1 |

I store the table in df and run the following data fragment query.

`df1= df.query('longitude == @x and latitude == @y and temperature== @z')`

Mostly I am getting the correct output.

Now I want to change the label value for my row matched by the query

`df.query('longitude == a and latitude == b and temperature== c')`

How can I update the label value matched by the query row. I tried using .replace , .iloc but None of them is giving me proper result.

Answer (score 0):

here it should be used  mask:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "longitude": ["x", "p", "a", "k"],
        "latitude": ["y", "q", "b", "l"],
        "temperature": ["z", "r", "c", "m"],
        "label": [1, 2, 1, 1],
    }
)

new_label = 3

df["label"] = df["label"].mask(
    (df["longitude"] == "a") & (df["latitude"] == "b") & (df["temperature"] == "c"),
    new_label,
)
df
```

| longitude | latitude | temperature | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | y | z | 1 |
| p | q | r | 2 |
| a | b | c | 3 |
| k | l | m | 1 |